# Plot numpy array of [x,3] on the same graph

Tags: python, numpy

How to plot a NumPy array such that each horizontal line `output[0],output[1],output[2].......` from the numpy array below corresponds to 3 dots `output[0][0]`, `output[0][1]`, `output[0][2]` on x-axis value 1, the next points is  `output[1][0]`, `output[1][1]`, `output[1][2]` corresponds to x-axis value 2.

And the similar positions in the `output[z][0]` are connected with a line such that `output[0][0]` , `output[1][0]`, `output[2][0]`, `output[3][0]`, .....are all connected with a line.

```
array([[112.00686535, 122.94385176, 32.6615162 ],
       [122.02063079, 142.95451678, 42.66445891],
       [132.04269772, 112.98105083, 52.6898423 ],
       ...,
```

The above numpy array example has a shape of `[2000,3]`

The output may look like

[image]

For example, `x-axis` value `2` represents `output[2]` = `output[2][0]`, `output[2][1]`, `output[2][2]`

Comment: Please add a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: Matplotlib's `plt.plot(arr)` is a good start. Then you can add embellishments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out plotly gives a nice, interactive graph.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + 5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) - 5

# Create traces
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='lines+markers'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y2,
                    mode='markers', name='markers'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

For an output with shape [x,3], we can pass

```
y=output[:,0] , y=output[:,1], y=output[:,2]
```

to each line individually

i.e.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=output[:,0],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, with Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([[112.00686535, 122.94385176, 32.6615162 ],
               [122.02063079, 142.95451678, 42.66445891],
               [132.04269772, 112.98105083, 52.6898423 ]])
df = pd.DataFrame(xs, index=np.arange(1, len(xs)+1))
df.plot(xticks=df.index)
```

---

[image]